# convert byte array into gif in java/android

Tags: java, android, gif, animated-gif

In my android app i receive an array of bytes from a server and have to convert them into a .gif image and then place it in a view.
I already know how to convert them into a still image using BitmapFactory, but the images always come out still.
I am using [gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) as my container view for the .gif image. I have tested it with a local animated gif and it works great.
How can i put the byte array into the gif-drawable view?

in the layout i have this:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgExerciseImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="exercise image" />
```

this is a view similar to an ImageView that can display animated gifs

I Want to display in it an image that i receive from my firebase server. this is the code:

```
imageRef.getBytes(DatabaseConstants.ONE_MEGABYTE * 3).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                imgExerciseImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

the byte[] is the animated gif. but in order to put it in my view i have to use the byte[] to form an image. in this example, im using BitmapFactory to create a bitmap. how can i create a gif instead of a bitmap?

Comment: Why not convert the input stream to an image? Plenty of support for that. No need to read the entire thing into a byte array yourself.

Comment: Because I'm using firebase and I can't get anything except a byte array

Comment: What de you mean by that? You will receive a stream of bytes. Not a byte array. It is up to you what you do with the bytes. If you put them in an array yes then you have a byte array.

Comment: Further it it unclear what the bytes would represent. What do they contain if you have to convert them to gif? A jpg? A png? A bmp? Isnt it already a gif image?

Comment: To use firebase you use a function to read the info from the server and then you receive the data in a callback that has a byte array parameter. I don't have any interaction with the inputstream

Comment: The bytes represent a gif. How would I insert them into a view?

Comment: So you receive the contents of a gif file? Well then there is nothing to convert i would think.

Comment: What is your exact problem? If you can do it with a local gif from file then why not with a gif in memory? You could first write those bytes to file if you only can handle gifs in files.

Comment: I have changed the question and added code samples so that you understand my situation better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears that gif-drawable comes with a GifDrawable object that can receive a byte array in it's constructor to create an animated gif that can then be placed in a GifImageView

```
try {
    GifDrawable gif = new GifDrawable(bytes);
    imgExerciseImage.setImageDrawable(gif);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```